# How to get to the right Django documentation?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django. I'm very familiar with Python. We're working with Django 1.8 (I thought with 1.18... this was part of my confusion but by far not all). In most cases I try to find documentation Google sends me to documentation of other versions of Django. This has been quite confusing. With Drupal I can just add `d6` or `d7` to my search query in Google to get to the right place. Not so with Django it seems.

How do you (experienced Django devs) get to the right page with the right documentation for the version you're working with?

The bottom right corner has a version number. Doesn't really help me to get to the right docs though.

[image]

Comment: The bottom right corner of the doc? It helps to stay up to date on the version of django, if you're using one of the supported versions, its easy enough to find the correct page

Comment: Plus the version is clearly in the URL.

Comment: You are on the Spanish version of the docs (es). Unless you really want Spanish, switch to English using the switcher above the version number. You'll still get some 404s if you substitute `1.10` for `1.8` in the url, but this will happen *much* less often. For example the 1.8 version of the [email docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.18/topics/email/) does exist in English. Unfortunately, there has been an issue with Google search results, where you are often taken to the Spanish or Japanese docs, even if you search in English. If you get a 404, make sure you are on the English docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all languages have documentation available. For example, 1.8 may not be in Japanese, but 1.9 and 1.10 are (and according to your screenshot, same for Spanish)

The URL at docs.djangoproject.com also has a version chooser, e.g.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/search/?q=filefield

What I do is go to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/

There's a floating box at the lower right where you can choose the documentation version.

Then on the right sidebar, I click download as HTML to save it locally. No need to worry if you're on the right version now.

BTW there is no 1.18, it's just 1.8!

Comment: Yeah apart from taking me to different versions of Django Google also takes me to different language versions (that are mostly completely in English). I guess Django docs are not structured properly for Google. So it's best to directly go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ when on 1.8...